# Rails: Appending URL parameters & removing URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

EDIT: **`See below unanswered part II.`**

*(ANSWERED)* I.  **Appending URLS**

I am trying to stack parameters in my view by using basic parameter guidelines:

`users_path(:a => 'test')`

The above would return: `?a=test`

However, I want to be able to consecutively click:

`users_path(:b => 'goat')`

and have it return `?a=test&b=goat`

Any suggestions on how to stack/append these URL params?

***(NOT ANSWERED)*** II. **Removing parameters**

If I want to add a `[x]` link next to a parameter setting, how could I then remove its respective parameter?

*(ANSWERED)* III. **Removing `page` Parameter**

I would like to remove the `page` parameter when a user selects a parameter choice. Is there a way to do this? It's clear that if I select 'Sports' as a parameter category, pagination shouldn't remain on page, 26, for example.

Comment: Using the session is not an option I assume?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to append the current parameters, you could try this:

```
users_path(params.merge(:b => 'goat'))
```

You may want to write a helper method that does this for you:

```
def merged_with_current_params(additional)
  params.merge(additional)
end
```

As to the second part of your question, you probably want to expand the incoming `params` into a series of checkboxes with the names and values set appropriately. Disabling the checkbox and submitting the form would have the effect of removing that param from the request.

To remove `:page` parameter, add this to your helper instead:

`params.except(:page).merge(additional)`

Comment: Interesting: Do you have any suggestions on how to NOT pass the `per_page` parameter? I would like pagination to reset when a new parameter is selected.

Comment: params.except(:per_page).merge(additional)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm thinking the checkbox solution is best, but is there a way to remove a parameter with a link?

Comment: You can't remove something from a link using a link. What I mean is to make a form that submits with `method='GET'` instead, turning it into a link of sorts.

Comment: Hm, that might be tricky considering I'm using AJAX, but I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.query_parameters` to use only the params needed, like so:

```
users_path(request.query_parameters.merge(:b => 'goat'))
```